# questions for dynamic binding and signature method in java ab

Tags: java, methods, signature

Matching a method signature and binding a method implementation are two sepearate issue 
so ,what's wrong with the follows code?

```
Container c5 = new JButton();

Object c6 = new JButton();

c5.add(c6);       //----it is wrong,why?
```

for me , c5 is a reference variable which contain reference to object of JButton,and JButton extends the class Component,so it should be right
so why ?

Answer (score 1):

Java is a [Single-Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch#Single_and_multiple_dispatch) language.  That means its method signature analysis is done at compile time, not run time.

The type of `c6` is `Object`.  (Yes, you assign a `JButton`, but the declared type of the variable is still `Object`.)  So when Java looks at `c5` (a `Container`) and its methods, it doesn't see an `add()` method that takes an Object.  So it flags it as an error.

Comment: I got it , one more question :you say java is a single-dispatch language,method signature analysis done at compile time ,not run time!  so I want to make a deeping learing for the difference between compile time and  run time .Could you reference one or two books about that mechanism ?   appreciate it for your help